# Powering Shift Register turns all Outputs High

Tags: integrated-circuit, shift-register

Note:I dont know much about ICs and made a post regarding this one already, so please understand if I get some basics wrong

I am trying to use a [Signetics 74199 Shift register](https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/502852/Signetics/74199/1) and connected the pins like this:
VCC to 5v, GND to ground, MR unconnected, which should reset the shift register. However, all the outputs turn high (That is, all LEDs connected to them turn on). Did I connect anything wrong or is the shift register just broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless specifically stated there is no expectation of the flip-flops taking on any particular state on power-up. Could be all high, all low or some of each.

If you want to make them all low, you have to pulse (or pull) /MR low (leaving it open is more-or-less the same as pulling it high, just more noise sensitive- a characteristic of those ancient TTL parts). To do this more properly you can add a 1K pullup and a N.O. 'reset' switch to GND.

If it was a CMOS part, leaving it open would have indeterminate results. There are no modern logic gates that I can think of where open= low in general (not a specific oddball part with a pull-down). 1960s RTL may have been the last.

Comment: Thanks :) I will keep that in mind when working with ICs in the future

Comment: Ok, I can reset the outputs now. However, when I apply voltage to the J input pin, while MR and Not-K are high and Not-CE is low and then switch the clock pin from low to high, all outputs turn high again. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: The /MR input is level-sensitive so simply pulling it low with a switch will work, however you’ll need debouncing for the clock input if using a mechanical switch. This is outside the scope of your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

- Initially, the capacitor will have no charge and hence the voltage will be at 0V resetting the chip. You may have to tweak values a bit.
- 5RC later the capacitor will charge and then you will have 5V at MR which will enable the chip to come out of the reset state.
- Pressing the button will give you an active low pulse.

---

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZigzx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>